# How iterate a fetch_assoc() array?

Tags: php, mysqli

Im a very novice programmer, i work with PHP and a have a doubt/problem with fetch_assoc().

I have this method that return the result of the database consult:

```
public function getUsuarios() {
    try {
        $resultado = $this->conexion->query("SELECT * FROM login_usuarios");
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception("Error al obtener los usuarios de la base de datos. Código de error: ".mysqli_errno);
    } finally {
        if($this->conexion != null) {
                $this->conexion->close();
        }
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

This script iterate and show the data of the database consult's result:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Código</td>
        <td>Nombres</td>
        <td>Apellidos</td>
    </tr>
    <?php while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($usuarios)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php print($fila['codUsuario']); ?></td>
        <td><?php print($fila['nombres']); ?></td>
        <td><?php print($fila['apellidos']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    $usuarios->free();
    ?>
</table>
```

With this way, all worked fine (but i don't understand what xD, i've see this way in a forum).

But, i've see other way in many sites. With this way the script stand like this:

```
// first convert the result to a fetch_assoc
$usuarios = (new Consultas)->getUsuarios()->fetch_assoc();

  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Código</td>
        <td>Nombres</td>
        <td>Apellidos</td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($usuarios as $fila) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php print($fila["codUsuario"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php print($fila["nombres"]); ?></td>
        <td><?php print($fila["apellidos"]); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    $usuarios->free();
    ?>-->
</table>
```

But with this way i have a **Illegal string offset mysql**. This looks like the foreach iterate on each column and not on each row.

Why the first way works and the second way don't?, How works mysqli_fetch_array($result) and fetch_assoc()?

Thanks for help.

Comment: There is example in documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php To answer your "why" question try `var_dump` your `$usuarios` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Construction `finally` closes connection before your call `fetch_assoc()`.

Try to comment `$this->conexion->close();`.

Your code iterates through row. `mysqli_result::fetch_assoc` return only one row. Please, read the documentation.

Comment: Not only that - OP iterates over fields of a single row, not over the result set.

Comment: Oh.. Yes. You right, just noticed. He tried to iterate through columns, not rows.